# Git merge local repository to previous revision?

Tags: git, version-control

I have just finished a feature on our dev branch it git, I commited my changes and pulled from the wrong branch, now I have stuff in the dev branch that shouldn't be there. I haven't pushed so it only in my local repo.

How can I revert to my local repo to the state it was at before I did the pull from the wrong branch?

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`.

Comment: I won't loose my changes with that that?

Comment: This command gives me: error: unknown switch `e'

Comment: nope, it wiped all of my changes. I backed the project up but now when I try to commit it keeps say there are no changes. Anyone know how to fix that.

Comment: 'no changes' is the expected result after a hard reset.  Your branch and worktree are back to the state they were in immediately after the commit before your pull, presuming that pull was really the last thing you'd done. Do `git diff HEAD^!` to see what changes were applied by your currently-checked-out commit. It's really not clear what you're doing.  The command I gave you has no `e` switch, so whatever got executed it wasn't that. There's something badly wrong somewhere in the process here.

Comment: the e switch issue was because i'm uing git shell. so i used `git reset --hard 'HEAD@{3}'`. the pull wasn't the last thing i did I fixed a merge too.

Comment: Maybe I went one too far i.e. it should have been `git reset --hard 'HEAD@{2}`. How can i commit what is in my file system to the branch seeing as my filesystem and git are out of sync?

Comment: Okay, maybe we can turn this into something generally valuable.  do `git config --global alias.lgdo '! git log --graph --decorate --oneline "${@---all}"'` and then `git lgdo --topo-order --reflog --all`. Update the question with the output (you can truncate it when you're sure you've seen all the relevant commits) and whatever you can make of it with say fifteen minutes' staring at it and research, and we'll do another round.  edit: there's a space between the `!` and the `git`.